# Devise sign_out action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

Ruby 1.8, Rails 2.3.15, devise 1.0.10 and warden 0.10.3

I have implemented admin using this example: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.0. When I sign out it show the message but I can still acess those page without signing in again. Can anyone let me know what is wrong with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a separate subdomain for admin views?

Comment: no i am not using subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

SInce you have not added any code, I can just guess that you have missed out the before filter:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

use this in the controller abouve all methods, this method is available by devise.